# Deserialize BulkAPI XML response to QueryResult

Tags: bulk-api, deserialize

Is there anyway to deserialize bulkAPI response(XML) to Standard QueryResult object?

I am using C# as backend and PartnerAPI of SFDC. See below XML.

[image]

I am getting "queryResult xmlns='http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload'> was not expected." Error while deserializing.

Comment: can u share ur current code.. how r u calling the bulk api from ur c# code ? did u look into using any helper library like this one - https://github.com/lfreeland/Salesforce-Bulk-API-Starter

Comment: Thanks Vamsi Krishna! I am using the same code but it returns result of query(select query) in XML format, however I would like it to be in native QueryResult object of Partner API.

Answer (score 0):

Different APIs uses XML structure with different namespaces. Partner API uses different namespace than bulk API so obviously they are not compatible. If you wanted, you will have to write that transformation yourself.

Comment: Okay.. No Problem.